# Django models foreign key in unicode outpu

Tags: python, django

I have one to many relationship with model Year and it has a foreign key with another model Compound.  I am trying to get the Django admin widget to include the class name so that it can be pulled from the drop down /autocomplete.

I have it something like

```
def __unicode__(self):
        return u'(%s) %d' % (self.compound.compound_name, self.year)
```

But this doesn't return the compound name as I expect but all attribute in the model compound.

```
class Year(models.Model):
    compound = models.ForeignKey('Compound', blank=False, null=False)
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'(%s) %d' % (self.compound.compound_name, self.year)

class Compound(models.Model):
    dif_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default='UnKnown')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default='SM')
    compound_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='UnKnown')
    phase = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(db_index=True, default=0)

def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s %d' % (self.dif_id,self,type,self.compound_name,self.phase )
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Compounds'
```

Any idea how I should get the compound_name? 
And also, I am looking to improve it by checking if the compound_name is Unknown the display the dif_id .

Thanks

Comment: `Year` has a `ForeignKey` to a model called `MoleculeDictionary`, not `Compound`.

Comment: The code looks fine. Please show an example of what you mean by the output showing "all attribute in the model compound".

Comment: In year instead of having Compound_name for compound I have dif_id type compoundname phase  year.

Comment: something like this "12 FM Cistern 4 1985". I would like to have "Cistern  1985" or If I don't have a compound name (Cistern) then "12 1985"